# MATLAB image transformation

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, matlab

The following code descripes the affine transformation of an image, I,

```
T = [sx, 0, 0;...
      0, sy, 0;...
      0, 0, 1];
tform = maketform('affine', T);
[J,cdata,rdata] = imtransform(I,tform);
```

After obtaining the transformed image, J, I want to find the appropriate pixel value of I(5,5) on image J.

What should I do?

[image]

[image]

My code is

```
function test()
    sx = 0.5; sy = 1;
    theta = pi/4;
    Ts = [sx, 0, 0;...
    0, sy, 0;...
    0, 0, 1];
    Tr = [cos(theta) -sin(theta) 0;...
          sin(theta) cos(theta), 0; ...
          0, 0, 1];
    T = Ts*Tr;

    I = imread('image_0002.jpg');
    tform = maketform('affine', T);
    [J,xdata,ydata] = imtransform(I,tform);
    h = ydata(2) - ydata(1);
    w = xdata(2) - xdata(1);

    %%
    gridOx = meshgrid(1:50:size(I,2), 1:50:size(I,1));
    gridOy = meshgrid(1:50:size(I,1), 1:50:size(I,2))';
    go = [gridOy(:), gridOx(:), ones(length(gridOx(:)),1)];

    for i=1:size(go,1)
        I = makept(I, go(i,1), go(i,2));
    end
    imshow(I);

    %%
    gt = T*go';

    TL = T*[1,1,1]';
    BL = T*[size(I,1), 1, 1]';
    TR = T*[1, size(I,2), 1]';
    BR = T*[size(I,1), size(I,2), 1]';
    minr = min([TL(1), TR(1), BL(1), BR(1)]);
    minc = min([TL(2), TR(2), BL(2), BR(2)]);

    %%
    gt = int32(round(gt));
    r = gt(1,:) - minr+1;
    c = gt(2,:) - minc+1;

    figure,hold on;
    for i=1:length(r)
        J = makept(J, r(i), c(i));
        plot(gt(1, i), gt(2, i));
    end
    figure, imshow(J);

    close all;
end

function I = makept(I, r, c)
    mr = max(r-2,1);
    mc = max(c-2,1);
    maxr = min(r+2,size(I,1));
    maxc = min(c+2,size(I,2));

    I(mr:maxr, mc:maxc,:) = 0;
    I(mr:maxr, mc:maxc,1) = 255;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way.. use 'tformfwd'.. we need to apply a scaling as well as explained in http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/02/14/spatial-transformations-maketform-tformfwd-and-tforminv/

```
         function [new_im, grn, gcn] = transformImage(I, gr, gc, TM)
              [new_im xdata ydata] = imtransform(I, TM);
              w = xdata(2)-xdata(1) +1;
              h = ydata(2)-ydata(1)+1;
              scalex = size(new_im,2)/w;
              scaley = size(new_im,1)/h;

              % cartesian coordinates
              go = [gc(:), gr(:)];

              %% cartesian coordinates
              NPt = tformfwd(TM, go);

              % convert to image coordinates
              NPtImage(:,1) = NPt(:,1) - xdata(1) + 1;
              NPtImage(:,2) = NPt(:,2) - ydata(1) + 1;
              NPtImage(:,1) = NPtImage(:,1)*scalex;
              NPtImage(:,2) = NPtImage(:,2)*scaley;
              NPtImage = round(NPtImage);

              grn = NPtImage(:,2);
              gcn = NPtImage(:,1);
              grn = reshape(grn, size(gr,1), size(gr,2));
              gcn = reshape(gcn, size(gc,1), size(gc,2));

              showimgs = false;
              if showimgs
                  I = uint8(I);
                  new_im = uint8(new_im);

                  figure, imshow(I), hold on;
                  for i=1:size(go,1)
                      plot(go(i,1), go(i,2), 'r*');
                  end

                  figure, imshow(new_im, 'XData', xdata, 'YData', ydata);
                  hold on
                  axis on
                  for i=1:size(go,1)
                      plot(NPt(i,1), NPt(i,2), 'r*')
                  end

                  tmpim = new_im;
                  for i=1:size(NPtImage,1)
                      tmpim = makept(tmpim, NPtImage(i,2), NPtImage(i,1), 'b');
                  end
                  figure, imshow(tmpim);
              end

              end


              function I = makept(I, r, c, color)
              mr = max(r-2,1);
              mc = max(c-2,1);
              maxr = min(r+2,size(I,1));
              maxc = min(c+2,size(I,2));

              I(mr:maxr, mc:maxc,:) = 0;

              if strcmp(color, 'r')
                  I(mr:maxr, mc:maxc,1) = 255;
              else
                  I(mr:maxr, mc:maxc,3) = 255;
              end
              end
```

Answer (score 7):

You transform the pixel coordinates just like you transformed the image.

```
appropriatePixel = J(T*[5;5;1]);
```

### EDIT

The code you posted was already quite close. Always remember that with images, the origin for images is in the top left and that the order of image dimensions is columns-rows, unlike with matrices. You took this into account in some places, but not everywhere.

The code below should fix the problem. `gt = T*go` was changed to use the transpose of T, and `minc` and `minr` were swapped.

```
function airplane()
       close all
       sx = 0.5; sy = 1;
       theta = pi/4;
       Ts = [sx, 0, 0;...
       0, sy, 0;...
       0, 0, 1];
       Tr = [cos(theta) -sin(theta) 0;...
           sin(theta) cos(theta), 0; ...
           0, 0, 1];
       T = Ts*Tr;

       I = imread('airplane2.png');
       tform = maketform('affine', T);
       [J,xdata,ydata] = imtransform(I,tform);

        %% 
       gridOx = meshgrid(1:50:size(I,2), 1:50:size(I,1));
       gridOy = meshgrid(1:50:size(I,1), 1:50:size(I,2))';
       go = [gridOx(:), gridOy(:), ones(length(gridOx(:)),1)];

       figure; imshow(I); hold on;
       scatter(go(:,1), go(:,2), 25, 'rs', 'filled');

       %%
       gt = T'*go'; 

       TL = T*[1,1,1]';
       BL = T*[size(I,1), 1, 1]';
       TR = T*[1, size(I,2), 1]';
       BR = T*[size(I,1), size(I,2), 1]';
       minc = min([TL(1), TR(1), BL(1), BR(1)]);
       minr = min([TL(2), TR(2), BL(2), BR(2)]);


       %%
       gt = int32(round(gt));
       r = gt(1,:) - minr+1;
       c = gt(2,:) - minc+1;

       figure; imshow(J);hold on;
       scatter(c, r, 25, 'rs', 'filled');

end
```

Result:
[image: itsaplane]

Comment: no.. if I transform a pixel coordinate the transform pixels may be [-5.5, -20].

Comment: Right. Based on the example I was thinking of (positive) scaling transforms only. Well in that case, first do this transform on all four corners of the image, take the minimum x and y and subtract that from the above, and add one, so that the origin is back at 1,1.

Comment: What `sx` and `sy` are you testing with?

Comment: Thank you very much.. I found another way to solve this problem.. I added the answer... We need to scale it as well..

Comment: When the transformed image is big matlab rescales it.. so we need to multiply by a scaling factor... as NPtImage(:,1) = NPt(:,1) - xdata(1) + 1;
              NPtImage(:,2) = NPt(:,2) - ydata(1) + 1;      we need to do it at this point...        gt = int32(round(gt));
       r = gt(1,:) - minr+1;
       c = gt(2,:) - minc+1;.. anyway thank you very much for your answer and effort.... really thank you..
              NPtImage(:,1) = NPtImage(:,1)*scalex;
              NPtImage(:,2) = NPtImage(:,2)*scaley;

Comment: for more http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/02/14/spatial-transformations-maketform-tformfwd-and-tforminv/